# Facebook integration for real photobooth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I've created a real photobooth which is a camera in a housing with an raspberry pi running a webserver and handling all the photo stuff. The frontend for this is an tablet with a browser pointing at the webserver running on the pi (on local network).

The functions are pretty simple: Take a picture (or a strip of four), view the gallery,  download and mail the photos. Now I'd like to integrate a photo upload to Facebook.

Is this possible with an application that is not hosted public? The booth has internet access via 3G or available Wifi. But the pi's webserver is only available locally.

My first Idea was to have the postback send to a script running on my website that redirects me hardocded to the local adress. This is working, but is this allowed?

For publish permissions I need to submit the app for review. But how can Facebook review my app? It's not available public.

Thank you in advance.
Arne

Comment: If you want to upload to user's fb profile, then checkut this doc, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0

Comment: Thank you. My question is how to send in a local app for review? The app is only available in my photo booth.